# Snowflake Javascript to count between two element in a array

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an array with dates in ascending order, I am trying to create a Snowflake UDF to count the array element between two dates.

The function should get the two days and tell us the count between the two days.

```
    create or replace function workdays_between(date1 String, date2 String)
 RETURNS double
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
  as 
  $$
  var DATE1 = DATE1
  var DATE2 = DATE2
  var count = 1
  var i = 1
  a = ["2017-01-01","2017-01-02","2017-01-03","2017-01-06","2017-01-09","2017-01-10"]
  if (DATE1 < DATE2) {
    for (i=1;a[i]<=DATE2;i++) {
        if (a[i] >= DATE1) {
         count = count + 1;
         }
      }
  }
    else
    {
        for (i=1;a[i]<=DATE1;i++) {
        if (a[i] >= DATE2) {
         count = count + 1;
        }
        }
        count = count * -1;
  }
     return count;
  $$
```

But I am not getting the desired output, please help.

Comment: Why are there hard coded days in the proposed solution? Why a UDF and not SQL math?

Comment: I had all these dates in a table and created a SQL function to calculate the workdays between two days all I need just select count(*) from workdaystable where dates between startdate and enddate , when I make it as a function and do a join with tables it is doing left outer join and aggregation,  because of the fact aggregation happens after joining, record length becomes huge, aggregation takes time to complete.

Answer (score 1):

the problem was with the case on DATE1 and DATE2, I gave in lower case inside the program, it worked after making it to upper case.